# what is the different between this in php?

Tags: php4

what is the difference between

```
$totalprice += $product['price'] * $product['count'];
```

and

```
$totalprice = $product['price'] * $product['count'];
```

both give the same result. so what's the use of (+=) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` is a shorthand for adding the result to the target.  The first one is equivalent to:

`$totalprice = $totalprice + ($product['price'] * $product['count']);`

There are also other compound operators `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc.

Comment: @sagarmatha you're getting the same result because `$totalprice` is presumably currently 0, but you're doing the extra processing.  If you have globals auto-register, or set this value somewhere else, that value could change.

Answer (score 1):

They only give the same result if $totalprice starts off at 0 or uninitialised

The += syntax is shorthand for the following:

```
$myvar += a;
```

is equivalent to

```
$myvar = $myvar + a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+=` takes `$totalprice` and adds `$product['price'] * $product['count']` to it.
The `=` asigns the value of `$product['price'] * $product['count']` to `$totalprice`.

If you are getting the same result, its because `$totalprice` started off equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If `$totalprice` is zero to start, then they're the same.  Otherwise, they're different.

As others have pointed out, `$i += $j` is shorthand for `$i = $i + $j`.